# Sandboxes - Full versus Partial Copy - Same Except Storage

Tags: administration, sandbox, architecture, environment, rootstock

I cannot find anything that clearly states this fact, and it's important in my dealings with a consultant's co-worker who is being difficult.

- **Full Sandbox**
- **Partial Copy Sandbox**

The different between these that Partial Copy has **only 5GB of storage**.  *That's effectively it.*  Correct?

I feel that this particular post confirms what I feel I've known for years:
[Intro To Environments (in Salesforce)](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Environments)

Comment: A specific Help article that also seems to confirm:   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=create_test_instance.htm

Comment: Related "minor note":  In my investigation of this, I have CREATED a partial sandbox.   So far (first morning) all plugins are behaving as expected (the consultant is for Rootstock and claims it cannot be put into a Partial, only a Full - not because of DATA STORAGE, because Rootstock ITSELF cannot run in Partial.   Partial = Full with less storage, I say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more differences.

- A `Full Sandbox` can only be refreshed every 29 days, whereas a `Partial Copy Sandbox` can be refreshed every 5 days.
- Only sample data is copied to a `Partial Copy Sandbox` on creation/refresh,  whereas all data is copied over to  a `Full Sandbox`.
- For a `Partial Copy Sandbox`, The 5GB limit on file storage is different in addition to the overall data storage limit.

See this chart from [Sandbox Licenses and Storage by Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=0).

[image: Sandbox Feature Quick Reference]

Apparently a `Sandbox Template` is also required for any `Partial Copy Sandbox`.

[Sandbox Management Best
Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015300000036AisAAE) also has some recommendations for when to use each type of sandbox:

[image: Sandbox Type & Use Case Alignment]

See also: [Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_sandbox.htm).

> ### Sandbox Limits
>
> - You can refresh a Full sandbox 29 days after you created or last refreshed it. If you delete a Full sandbox within those 29 days, you need to wait until after the 29 day period, from the date of last refresh or creation, to replace it.
> - You can refresh a Partial Copy sandbox 5 days after you created or last refreshed it. If you delete a Partial Copy sandbox within those 5 days, you need to wait until after the 5 day period, from the date of last refresh or creation, to replace it.
> - You can refresh a Developer or Developer Pro sandbox once per day.
>   Enterprise Edition includes licenses for 25 Developer sandboxes and 1 Partial Copy sandbox.
> - Performance Edition includes licenses for 1 Full sandbox, 5 Developer Pro sandboxes, 100 Developer sandboxes, and 1 Partial Copy sandbox.
> - Unlimited Edition includes licenses for 1 Full sandbox, 5 Developer Pro sandboxes, and 100 Developer sandboxes and 1 Partial Copy sandbox.
> - Professional Edition includes licenses for 10 Developer sandboxes. (Change sets aren’t available.)
>
> If you need licenses for more sandboxes, contact Salesforce to order sandboxes for your organization.
>
> ### Sandbox Storage Limits
>
> - Partial Copy sandboxes have a 5 GB of files and a 5 GB of data storage limit.
> - Developer Pro sandboxes have a 1 GB of files and a 1 GB of data storage limit.
> - Developer sandboxes have a 200 MB of files and a 200 MB of data storage limit.
> - Full sandboxes have the same storage limit as your production organization.
> - Sandboxes don’t send email notifications when storage limits are reached. However, if you reach the storage limit of your sandbox, you can’t save new data in your sandbox. To check your storage limits, from Setup, enter Storage Usage in the Quick Find box, then select Storage Usage in your sandbox.

Comment: I'd lide to add that in a partial copy you can select the tables where you'll pull your data from... But there's no guarantee you'll have relevant data (relationships can be empty), as the storage is limited. The partial copy is oddly use-cased in my opinion

Of course the full sandbox doesn't have that issue as it'll copy the data connecting with their relationships

Comment: Great answer.  It's much appreciated.    Ultimately, in my attempt to keep things simplistic.... they are the same with a data limit.  Yes, refresh rate this and template that and which records you get the other....  totally agreed.  ;-)    Being told an APP cannot be installed to a Partial Copy Sandbox which CAN go to a Full Sandbox....     I saw it (and was correct in my case) as a "unless you are storing GIGS OF DATA with the default app, or have Gigs of REQUIRED data for the app, that's bologna.    :-)